# Python lambdas for __bool__, __str__, etc

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, duck-typing

Often in Python it is helpful to make use of duck typing, for instance, imagine I have an object `spam`, whose `prompt` attribute controls the prompt text in my application. Normally, I would say something like:

```
spam.prompt = "fixed"
```

for a fixed prompt. However, a dynamic prompt can also be achived - while I can't change the spam class to use a *function* as the `prompt`, thanks to *duck typing*, because the userlying spam object calls `str`, I can create a **dynamic** prompt like so:

```
class MyPrompt:
    def __str__( self ):
        return eggs.get_user_name() + ">"

spam.prompt = MyPrompt()
```

This principal could be extended to make any attribute dynamic, for instance:

```
class MyEnabled:
    def __bool__( self ):
        return eggs.is_logged_in()

spam.enabled = MyEnabled()
```

Sometimes though, it would be more succinct to have this inline, i.e.

```
spam.prompt = lambda: eggs.get_user_name() + ">"
spam.enabled = eggs.is_logged_in
```

These of course don't work, because neither the `__str__` of the lambda or the `__bool__` of the function return the actual value of the call.

I feel like a solution for this should be simple, am I missing something, or do I need to wrap my function in a class every time?

Comment: Skip the lambda and use just `spam.prompt = eggs.get_user_name() + ">"` - place a pair of parenthesis in the end of the method to actually call it: `spam.enabled = eggs.is_logged_in()`

Comment: You could have a look at the `@property` decorator.

Comment: @Heike or more generally on the descriptor protocol (the `property` type is just one single generic application of descriptors).

Comment: @Heike also note that descriptors are only invoked when they are class attributes, not when they are instance attributes so the solution here needs a bit more than just using descriptors ;-)

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I understand that descriptors are class attributes. What I meant was that OP could adapt the class definition of `spam.__class__` and use `@property` to create setter/getters for `spam.prompt` and `spam.enabled`.

Comment: @Heike yes that's what I was thinking too (well, it's the obvious solution isn't it ?) - what I meant is that the OP cannot just do something like `spam.prompt = property(some_getter_func)`.

Comment: @PauloScardine `spam.prompt = eggs.get_user_name() + ">"` would result in a  prompt fixed to whatever the user name was at the time of calling.

Comment: Wow, now I understand what you are trying to achieve - why not make `prompt` a dynamic property of spam instead? A good way to achieve lazy evaluation is placing the burden is on `spam`.

Answer (score 0):

What you want are computed attributes. Python's support for computed attributes is [the descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html), which has a generic implementation as [the builtin `property` type](https://docs.python.org/3.7/howto/descriptor.html#properties).

Now the trick is that, as documented (cf link above), descriptors only work when they are class attributes. Your code snippet is incomplete as it doesn't contains the definition of the `spam` object but I assume it's a class instance, so you cannot just do `spam.something = property(...)` - as the descriptor protocol wouldn't then be invoked on `property()`.

The solution here is the good old "strategy" design pattern: use properties (or custom descriptors, but if you only have a couple of such attributes the builtin `property` will work just fine) that delegates to a "strategy" function:

```
def default_prompt_strategy(obj):
    return "fixed"

def default_enabled_strategy(obj):
    return False


class Spam(object):
    def __init__(self, prompt_strategy=default_prompt_strategy, enabled_strategy=default_enabled_strategy):
        self.prompt = prompt_strategy
        self.enabled = enabled_strategy

    @property
    def prompt(self):
        return self._prompt_strategy(self)

    @prompt.setter
    def prompt(self, value):
        if not callable(value):
            raise TypeError("PromptStrategy must be a callable")
        self._prompt_strategy = value

    @property
    def enabled(self):
        return self._enabled_strategy(self)

    @enabled.setter
    def enabled(self, value):
        if not callable(value):
            raise TypeError("EnabledtStrategy must be a callable")
        self._enabled_strategy = value



class Eggs(object):
    def is_logged_in(self):
        return True

    def get_user_name(self):
        return "DeadParrot"

eggs = Eggs()

spam = Spam(enabled_strategy=lambda obj: eggs.is_logged_in())   
spam.prompt = lambda obj: "{}>".format(eggs.get_user_name())
```

Comment: I think in `Spam.__init__` it should be `self._prompt_strategy = prompt_strategy` etc., not `self.prompt = prompt_strategy`.

Comment: @Heike nope, it shouldn't - properties are binding descriptors (they implement `__set__(self, obj, value)`) so assigning to `self.prompt` etc works as expected by invoking the property's setter.